# How do you use a license key/server to authenticate a Flask app?

Tags: authentication, flask, flask-login

I have a service that generates a license key, and that provides an API to verify the key is valid, e.g. `curl api-url -d "license_key=xxxx" -X post` returns json that says if the key is valid or not.

I want to use this for authentication in a flask app, where the user enters their key to login, and the app does the check above to authenticate if they have access. The users don't need a username, the license key is unique to them, and should be all that is needed.

I have not found anything that (at least to my understanding) suggests how to go about this in either https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ or https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

I guess it isn't crucial it is done in Flask, if there is another way to do this with a regular web server.

Does this kind of authentication have a name? I feel like I am not looking for the right information so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using sessions in Flask. You can make the POST request with the `requests` module.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash, session
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret-key-goes-here"  

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    license_key = StringField("License key", validators = [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if session.get("authenticated"):
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        req = requests.post("api-url", {"license_key": form.license_key.data})
        if not req.json()["valid"]:
            flash("Invalid username or password")
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        session["authenticated"] = True
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
    return render_template("login.html", title="Sign In", form=form)
```

This assumes the JSON response is of the form `{"valid": true/false}`.